# Regression of a set of (2-element) vectors on another set of (2-element) vectors

Tags: matrix, fitting

As a trivial example, here are two vectors:

```
f = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}

s = {{-1, 2}, {-2, 4}, {-3, 6}, {-4, 8}}
```

It is instantly clear (apart from my sloppy formatting) that elements of `s` follow from elements of `f` according to `s = M.f`

where `M` = a matrix `{{-1, 0}, {0, 2}}`

I find the help details for the various forms of regression obscure, so my question is: more generally, how do I find the best fit matrix for such a (seemingly simple) correlation?

Comment: `f` and `s` are matrices and not vectors... anyway, what you have is referred to as a [Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis).

Comment: Would `LinearSolve` be helpful here? Or `LeastSquares`?

Comment: @J.M. Point taken. The problem stems from vector analysis, my data being orthogonal components of (speed, direction) vectors.

Comment: Anyway, `FindGeometricTransform[]` might interest you.

Comment: @J.M. Indeed it does! I think it solves my limited Procrustean problem, thank you.

Comment: If you figured out how to use `FindGeometricTransform[]`, feel free to write an answer to your own question explaining how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your matrix `M` is not unique because your example data is not linear independent. Therefore, we may get a different `M`. Note further, due to the shape of your data you must write `f.M` not `M.f`.

To get a least square solution, we first define an symbolic matrix and define an error function: `err` that measures the differences between `s` and `f.M`. Then we minimize the error by adjusting the parameters of the symbolic matrix:

```
f = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
s = {{-1, 2}, {-2, 4}, {-3, 6}, {-4, 8}};
mat = Array[Subscript[m, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}];
err = (s - f.mat)^2 // Flatten // Total;
sol = mat /. FindMinimum[err, Flatten[mat]][[2]]
s == f.sol

(*{{-4.53077, 0.778831}, {3.53077, 1.22117}}*)
(*True*)
```

Comment: `LeastSquares[f, s]` would accomplish the same thing, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, `LeastSquares` solves `m.x==b` where m is known. @MarcoB

Comment: Daniel, try this: `s == f . LinearSolve[f, s]` or `s == f . LeastSquares[f, s]`. They will both return `True`, exactly like your solution.

Comment: In fact, if you use `NMinimize` instead of `FindMinimum` in your code, you will get the same result as `LeastSquares`. I think `FindMinimum` just finds another one of the many possible solutions.

Comment: @Marco Hi, that's correct. I found the belonging information under "Generalisation&Extensions" in the help. Was new to m, one never stops learning.

Comment: This is deeper than I thought. f.sol is indeed = s. But the method does not find the simpler solution mat = g = {{-1, 0}, {0, 2}}. and I find that f.sol==f.g

Comment: Hi Anton, at first I was astonished too. But it is not so deep, because the role of mat and x in mat.x==b  may be interchanged by transposition: Transpose[x] . Transpose[mat]==Transpose[b]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three problems that get in the way of what I think you're asking.  I think you want to perform a regression on the following model (which also isn't the model I think you should be considering but that's another issue):

$$s_{i,j}=a_j f_{i,1}+ b_j f_{i,2}+\epsilon_{i,j}$$

where $\epsilon_{i,j}\sim N(0,\sigma_j)$ and $i=1,2,3,4$ and $j=1,2$.

(1)  You've got 6 parameters ($a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $\sigma_1$, and $\sigma_2$) and only 4 data points.  You need more data values for a reasonable example.

(2)  Having both predictors being identical for every data point (or even exactly linearly related) makes little sense.  That does not allow one to estimate separate effects for the two predictors.

(3)  The example data with the above model results in estimates of the $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ being zero which isn't very real world.  You need more complexity in the sample data.

If one uses `Solve` in the following manner

```
f = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
s = {{-1, 2}, {-2, 4}, {-3, 6}, {-4, 8}};
Solve[{s[[All, 1]] == a1 f[[All, 1]] + b1 f[[All, 2]], 
  s[[All, 2]] == a2 f[[All, 1]] + b2 f[[All, 2]]},
 {b1, b2, c1, c2}]
(* {{b1 -> -1 - a1, b2 -> 2 - a2}} *)
```

one sees that there is an infinite set of solutions for your sample data and the model I think you're considering.

In short you need a more realistic example if you think $\sigma_1>0$ and/or $\sigma_2>0$.

Comment: Entirely justified comments. I should have made it clear that I am dealing with a much larger data set than the brief example of four.